# Split string in SQL Server's xquery

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xquery

Is there a way to do something like the (unsupported) xquery tokenize in SQL Server?

I have:

```
<WITS:foo>
 <WITS:bars>
  <bar details="name=theName;value=theValue" other="false" stuff="true">
  </bar>
 </WITS:bars>
 <WITS:bars notThis="oneIdontwant">
  <bar></bar>
 </WITS:bars>
</WITS:foo>
```

and I want to pull out `theName`. The closest I have been able to come is to get `name=theName;value=theValue` via

```
SELECT
 x.query('
  distinct-values(
   for $name in data(//WITS:foo/WITS:bars[not (@notThis)]/WITS:bar[@details="name"))
   return $name
  )'
)
FROM (SELECT CAST(xmlColumn AS XML) x FROM blah Where blahblah) y
```

So far it looks like I'm out of luck since this is all running on SQL Server 2005, and from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178064%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) it seems like the only thing there is to work with strings is the four functions listed (no index-of, or other options).

Right now I'm parsing after the fact, but I was wondering if there are any other ways I could get this done server side.

Comment: Why can't you use the T-SQL string functions to extract it from what you have so far?

Comment: I can... that's what I'm doing right now, I was just wondering if there was any way to do it inside the xquery.  Looks like no.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you were able to get `name=theName;value=theValue`. You can use TSQL XML to split the items into rows. With the Query below.

```
declare @xml xml
SET @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace('name=theName;value=theValue',';','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'
SELECT t.value('.','NVARCHAR(20)') AS [delimited items] FROM @xml.nodes('//root/r') AS a(t)
```

From here, you can redo the same process to split `name=theName`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following string operations:

[SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) - Returns part of a character, binary, text, or image expression.

[CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) - Returns the starting position of the specified expression in a character string.

Note, the links refer to SQL Server 2005 functions.

I believe using CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING will be the easiest solution. An other way is to use regular expressions but they are not well supported even in newest versions and you will need to use CLR procedure - too complicated for such an sample task.